# ui-router resume preventedEvent

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I want users to be notified that they have to save changes when they navigate to another page.
Therefore I listen to the stateChangeStart Event of UI-ROUTER.
I need to prevent the event to prevent, that the next page doesn't load the values before they are saved. When I manually navigate to the desired page via $state.go(..) I keep hanging in a loop of stateChangeStart Events

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        ....
    });
    confirmPopup.then(function(res){
        ....
        }
        $ionicNavBarDelegate.back();
    });
});
```

How to log of the stateChangeStart-Event?

Edit:

```
$urlRouter.sync();
$state.go(toState.name, {id:toParams.id}, {reload: false});
```

Stays inside the loop.

Comment: If you need to reload the same state without going into infinite loop you may use : $state.go('your_state.name', {}, {reload: true}); I agree with @Mohammad Sepahvand right direction to achieve solve the mentioned issue :)

Comment: I'm not reloading the same state unfortunately, I load another state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$urlRouter.sync()
```

> Returns null.
>
> Triggers an update; the same update that happens when the address bar
>   url changes, aka $locationChangeSuccess. This method is useful when
>   you need to use preventDefault() on the $locationChangeSuccess event,
>   perform some custom logic (route protection, auth, config,
>   redirection, etc) and then finally proceed with the transition by
>   calling $urlRouter.sync().

[See docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlroutersync).

The use of the `urlRouter.sync()` is pretty obvious if you look at the docs, if you want to go to another state or want to check something in between the transition, you could also do this to prevent a redirect loop:

```
var nextState = null;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        if (next.name == nextState) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        nextState = next.name;
        $state.go(next.name);

});
```

Comment: Don't know how to apply this. Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: I am losing the state params like this. How to solve this ? Thank you

Comment: @alyn000r You can pass params to `$state.go()`, basically: `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState  , toParams, fromState, fromParams) {...})`